# Achieving a specific format in Apache Log4j

Tags: log4j, pattern-layout

I want to have following format in my log file in Log4j

{date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} {level} [{thread name- thread Id}]:[{file}:{line}] {message}

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to the javadoc about the pattern layout. You can find the javadoc for log4j 1.2.17 [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

However, I would recommend you to use Apache Log4j2 (even if it is currently in beta) or LogBack. Log4j2 provides many more options to do different pattern layouts, you can check it [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)

Comment: This answered my query, except for the thread id. I can include it in message itself but still would like to know if it is possible.